# Make query using Sequelize and NodeJS with other key in primary key

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, relationship, sequelize.js

I have a question that I lost time and nothing.

I have one model Price:

```
var price = sequelize.define('price', {
    price_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataType.INTEGER
    },
    carrier_mongo_id : {
        type: DataType.STRING,
        require : true,
        references: {
            model: "carrier",
            key: "carrier_mongo_id"
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
    },
    value: {
        type: DataType.DECIMAL
    }
});
```

I have other model Carrier:

```
 var carrier = sequelize.define('carrier', {
    carrier_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Datatype.INTEGER
    },
    carrier_mongo_id: {
        type: Datatype.STRING,
        require : true
    },
    name: {
        type: Datatype.STRING,
        require : true
    }
});
```

and make query like this:

```
carrierModel.hasMany(priceModel, {foreignKey: 'carrier_mongo_id'});

carrierModel.findAll({ include: [{ model: priceModel , required: true }] }).then(function(result){

    var aCarriers = new Array();

    result.forEach(function(carreteiro){
        aCarriers.push(carreteiro.dataValues);
    });

    console.log(aCarriers);

}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

my query is :

```
SELECT 
    `carrier`.`carrier_id`,
    `carrier`.`carrier_mongo_id`,
    `carrier`.`name`,    
    `prices`.`price_id` AS `prices.price_id`,
    `prices`.`carrier_mongo_id` AS `prices.carrier_mongo_id`,    
    `prices`.`value` AS `prices.value`
FROM
    `carrier` AS `carrier`
        INNER JOIN `price` AS `prices` ON `carrier`.`carrier_id` = `prices`.`carrier_mongo_id`
```

But I need this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    `carrier`.`carrier_id`,
    `carrier`.`carrier_mongo_id`,
    `carrier`.`name`,    
    `prices`.`price_id` AS `prices.price_id`,
    `prices`.`carrier_mongo_id` AS `prices.carrier_mongo_id`,    
    `prices`.`value` AS `prices.value`
FROM
    `carrier` AS `carrier`
        INNER JOIN `price` AS `prices` ON `carrier`.`carrier_mongo_id` = `prices`.`carrier_mongo_id`
```

I know that I can use this method Sequelize.query (...), but my question is:

How to make this query using Sequelize model

tks

Comment: Why are you using `string` instead of `integer`? Try to define `carrier_mongo_id` as `integer`

Comment: Hello @TilovYrys, the carrier_mongo_id is a hash id tks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my case guys =)

the fix is update the CarrierModel set up the carrier_mongo_id for primaryKey

```
 ........................
 carrier_mongo_id : {
    type: DataType.STRING,
    require : true,
    primaryKey: true,
    references: {
        model: "carrier",
        key: "carrier_mongo_id"
    },
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
    onDelete: 'cascade'
},
.....................
```

And the query is like :

```
 carreteiroModel.hasMany(precoModel, {foreignKey:         'carreteiro_mongo_id', otherKey: 'carreteiro_mongo_id'});
         carreteiroModel.findAll({ include: [{ model: precoModel ,    required: true }] }).
   then(function(result){ ...});
```

tks for you comments :)